# Getting the mode from an RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to get the mode (the most common number) from an rdd using Spark + Scala.

I can get it doing the following but I think it could be a better way to calculate this. The most important thing is if more than one value has the same number of repetition, I need to return both of them.

Let's see my example code:

```
val l = List(3,4,4,3,3,7,7,7,9)
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(l)
val grouped = rdd.map (e => (e, 1)).groupBy(_._1).map(e=> (e._1, e._2.size))
val maxRep = grouped.collect().maxBy(_._2)._2
val mode = grouped.filter(e => e._2 == maxRep).map(e => e._1).collect
```

And the result is right:

```
Array[Int] = Array(3, 7)
```

but is there a better way to do this? I mean considering the performance because the original RDD would be much bigger than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work and be a little bit more efficient.
*(only if you are sure the total number of elements is small)*

```
val counted = rdd.countByValue()
val max = counted.valuesIterator.max
val maxElements = count.collect { case (k, v) if (v == max) => k }
```

If there could be many elements, consider this alternative which is memory safe.

```
val counted = rdd.map(x => (x, 1L)).reduceByKey(_ + _).cache()
val max = counted.values.max
val maxElements = counted.map { case (k, v) => (v, k) }.lookup(max)
```

Comment: Thank you!, just a little detail: is `lookup` instead of `lookUp`.

Comment: @mjbsgll Right, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

How about get the max key-value pair from a double groupBy? This works even better for bigger data size.

```scala
rdd.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).groupBy(_._2).max

// res1: (Int, Iterable[(Int, Int)]) = (3,CompactBuffer((3,3), (7,3)))
```

To get the element

```scala
rdd.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).groupBy(_._2).max._2.map(_._1)

// res4: Iterable[Int] = List(3, 7)
```

The first `groupBy` will get element into `(element -> count)` with type `Map[Int, Long]`, the second `groupBy` will group `(element -> count)` by  `count`, like `(count -> Iterable((element, count))`, then simply `max` to get the key-value pair with the maximum key value, which is the `count`.